# Algebraic Solution to Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solving the equation $x^2=2^x$ algebraically.

I solved it graphically, however, upon solving this equation algebraically, I realized that I was not equipt with the necessary tools to solve it. I was not able to reduce it to anything solvable within the scope of my knowledge.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you asking us to provide you with an "algebraic" solution? Are you familiar with the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)?

Comment: No, I am not familiar with this function.